# Read tabs of website of dynamically generated content every 10s?

Tags: python, web-scraping

This website has some tabs like 1 minute, 5 minutes, etc...

[image]
[image]

https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/technicals/

I want to read the speedometer "NEUTRAL" text automatically and have Python print out every second what the status is (whether NEUTRAL or something else) for 1 minute and 15 minute in the terminal.

Currently do that by clicking on it every time I want an update, but they are not real links whose content can be fetched easily.

Is it even possible to "simulate" clicking on it and get the dynamically generated content using Python?

Comment: Check if they already have an API you can use to retrieve your data

Comment: Thanks. I checked. Afaik, their API is for other, technical, things rather than this specific item on their home page.

Comment: simulating a click can be preformed by python selenium, read more about that.

Comment: This page uses JavaScript to generate it. So it would need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript - and then you can click buttons and get new data. But using DevTools in Chrome/Firefox (tab: Network, filter: XHR) you can see javaScript send POST to `https://scanner.tradingview.com/crypto/scan` and it gets all values which you can see in tables below Summary - and it uses these information to generate plot. You could try to use these information to generate result.